# iOS provisioning after app transfer

Tags: ios, xcode, development-environment, ios-provisioning, apple-developer

I was developing an iOS app under my personal account and so far used Xcode's automatic signing feature for app provisioning. I now transferred the app to another organization that I'm not part of, but they want me to continue developing the app. They made my personal account where the app once was an "app manager" in their account for that particular app.

Now I'd like to submit an update for the app, but automatic signing does not work anymore. I get the error "Failed to create provisioning profile: the app ID cannot be registered to your development team", which is understandable since the app ID moved to the organization's account. I cannot have access to the organization's account since there are other apps there.

I'm sure there must be a way in such a scenario that I can continue uploading app updates for their account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask an organization (who/that own's your/this app now) to add you as a 'Team Member' in their Apple Developer Account. A team member can work with development environment only. It can create provisioning & certificates for development purpose only. A team member do not have right/permissions to update/change any other options in developer account.

As you are a developer for this app, they (organization) will allow you to access development resources. Share below information (link) to an app owner organization.

Here is more details about roles of users:  [Team Privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html)

[image]

**or**

 If you've your own apple developer account, then you can create new AppID, Bundle Identifier (for temporary development use) or wild Card Identifier (I recommend to use wild card identifier) to develop this app.

But if you want to upload/distribute app/updates on App store then you must have a **'Team Admin'** or **'Team Agent'** privilege. And I think you organization may not allow you the same role. But they can share your .p12 for distribution profile (Certificate or provisioning profile) by using which you can distribute an app on app store, without using to developer account.

> **I suggest and recommend, use .p12 profile to
>     distribute your app**

Comment: Thank you very much, you led me on the right path. They had to add me to the organization's team, now I can upload apps for them.